# What is the range of ECM jammer in Payday 2?

Tags: payday-2

What is the range of ECM jammer in Payday 2? Let's say I put it in the middle of the jewelry store's shopping room in the Jewelry Store Heist mission, how far it will reach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[One Jammer will cover the entire map](http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/0/864976115663341159/).

There is further discussion about the topic in the above link on the PAYDAY 2 Forums, but the people who HAVE tested it believe that it covers the entire map.

Comment: Interesting.  That being, a precision that might worth it, from the thread you mentioned: *Exception here. The camera who's "turn off" temporaly needs to be on the building with the jammer*

Comment: I would like to see more confirmations, but since this is the only answer with at least some suggestive investigations done in the given link, I'm accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The exact range of ECM is unknown, however, the range is limited and might or might not cover the whole map depending on its size. Update #12 shed some light on this question with the following.

> Buffed the ECM jammer by increasing the range -- [source](http://steamcommunity.com/games/218620/announcements/detail/2037040566416718108)